# JLabel won't update, using a timer to update the time every 3 seconds

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, timertask

Im creating a countdown timer, and using GUI w/ a JFrame. I am trying to using the label.setText(text); function and although I know Java is compiled, I thought that using the timer would update it every 3 seconds with the code I have. Any help please? I want to update the setText but it doesnt do so in my code, I have to rerun the code which essentially means my code doesnt work.

Ive tried adjusting my while loop and other statements, but I cant figure out whats wrong.

```
    int currentDay = now.getDayOfMonth(); 
    int currentHour = now.getHour();
    int currentMinute = now.getMinute();
    int currentSecond = now.getSecond();


JLabel lblMinutesLeft = new JLabel("Minutes Left: "+ (60-currentMinute));
    lblMinutesLeft.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblMinutesLeft.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblMinutesLeft.setBounds(125, 488, 160, 74);
    contentPane.add(lblMinutesLeft);

    JLabel lblSecondsLeft = new JLabel("Seconds Left: " + (60-currentSecond));
    lblSecondsLeft.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    lblSecondsLeft.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblSecondsLeft.setBounds(106, 573, 150, 50);
    contentPane.add(lblSecondsLeft);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
     TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                while (currentDay != 10) {
                    lblMinutesLeft.setText("Minutes Left: "+ (60-currentMinute));
                    lblSecondsLeft.setText("Seconds Left: " + (60-currentSecond));
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(tt, 1000, 3000);
```

Output should be updating every 3 seconds with the (60 - currentNum of seconds into the minute) and same with the minutes, so on and so forth.

Output on my GUI doesnt change.

Comment: Your variables `currentMinute` and `currentSecond` are set once in the beginning and **never** updated.

Comment: @PM77-1 Doesnt now.getMinute() and now.getSecond() update everytime it is called? I just tried that and even when updating every 3 seconds it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. And each of them is called once only.

Comment: @PM77-1 Okay so I have a question then, when I call my variable currentMinute, it only will display the value and will not update the value? If I were to put now.getMinute() into a function and assign the variable each time, it should update?

Comment: Yes and Yes. Variables store values.

Comment: @PM77-1 I tried that. It doesn't work

Comment: Have you by any chance tried it on 10th?

Comment: @PM77-1 All my variables like that were updated, I update it by the day I work on it.

Comment: All I meant was that you have `while (currentDay != 10) ` so if current day was 10 - you logic would have been skipped.